# Getting wrong compilation failed result in TeamCity

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity

I've added an external application to the building process of a MSBuild project (through an Exec task), and it is making TeamCity believe the compilation failed because it prints "Error ..." at the start of a line. However, it is not an error, and even if it actually would be one, the Exec task is set to ignore the exit code of the command, which is what the external app uses to notify of errors.

What can I do? I asked on the official some days ago, but haven't got any reply so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own application to hide the output.  Then read the exit code and fail or continue depending on how it went.

Comment: Marked this as the answer, as it seems to be the only way to solve the problem right now. However, I think of this more as a bug from TeamCity.